# jquery ajax return string not setting class

Tags: jquery, ajax, mobile, cordova

In my ajax(which pulls json data from a remote server) I am appending a html div to contain a link to another page, the class attribute of this link needs to be set to a function called "ajaxify". The thing is this works throughout the entire application no problem.. its when its appended in the ajax return function is where the error occurs and as a result this function doesnt load..

Well to be honest, sometimes it loads.. sometimes it doesnt!! typical javascript.

also if somebody could recommend me a good debugger for safari in windows it would also be greatly appreciated... Im currently running in the dark

here is the code

```
$.ajax({
    url: 'url',
    dataType: 'jsonp',
    jsonp: 'jsoncallback',
    timeout: 25000,
    success: function(data, status){
        $.each(data, function(i,item){
            var recipe = "<div class='icon-text'><a class='ajaxify' href='pages/onlineRecipe.html' onclick='$(setOnlineID("+item.id+"))' >"
                         +"<p><img alt='Image-alt' width='64' class='wrap-around' id='img"+item.id+"' />"
                         +"<strong>"+item.title+"</strong>"
                         +"<br/>"+item.desc+"</p></a></div>";

            $('#onlineList').append(recipe);
                var img = "#img" + item.id;
                $(img).attr('src', "data:image/png;base64,"+item.image);
        });
    },
    error: function(){
        output.text('Ha producido un error cargando el dato. Por favor, intèntalo de nuevo.');
    }
});
```

ive been stuck on this for a few hours now at this stage,, and its very annoying. Any help or suggestions would be greatly appreciated! Thanks in advance.

EDIT: this is being called in jquerys onload function "$(document).ready(function(){" therefore the html is fully loaded before the ajax appends the div with the link.. i wonder if this has anything to do with it??

Comment: why don't you use `$.getJSON` if you want to get JSON?

Comment: Is `ajaxify` a function or a class?

Comment: im using this method simply because it works (apart from the class thing).. however im new enough to these methods, so maybe as you say would be better.

Comment: ajaxify is a binded js function. Theres nothing wrong with that tho, it works everywhere except for here. if i simply put the html straight into the html page, it works perfectly. Its only when i append it becomes intermittent

Comment: Does it return your spanish error message if it doesn't work?

Comment: no it actually does work.. and if you click the link it directs you to the page but doesnt call ajax function.. which means the page gets loaded without any of my headers or other things i have included in index.html.

Comment: For debug, use firebug lite. And regarding "typical javascript", I would say that it depends on who's writing the code ;-)

Comment: Also, use double quotes in your html properties, and try to bind your onclick method using the `on` method instead of your inline onclick handler. http://api.jquery.com/on/

Comment: well ya i'll take that johan haa. always seems to be very peculiar tho.. sometimes it seems illogical to me! i said that because its not the first time ive seen intermittent code produced with javascript. Thanks for firebug lite tip.

Comment: What i understand so far:
1. Ajax function loads with success function.
2. Injection works properly 
3. The rendered link then doesnt work in the way you expect it.
now its more a hypothesis of mine... at another point you bind functions via $('.ajaxify)?
Those binds wouldnt apply to async loaded ankers afterwords. you would need to recall the bind...
else than that what you are telling leads me to the impression the part shown above works fine and the problem is somewhere else. 
could you explain how the class name "ajaxify" goes together with the function?

Comment: Sidrich your bang on right, this is the conclusion i came to about 2 days ago. So i just called the ajaxify function again and boom. works perfect :) how do i mark yours as correct answer tho??

Answer (score 0):

First things first, *the error handler* is not called with *.ajax* call in case of *JSONP request*

***From jQuery documentation:***

```
error(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown)

    Note: This handler is not called for cross-domain script and JSONP requests.
```

Try this

```
$.ajax({ url: 'url',
  dataType: 'jsonp',
  timeout: 10000,
  jsonp: "callback",
  jsonpCallback: callbackMethod,
});

function callbackMethod(jsonData) {
// this would be called on callback
}
```

Check this out for further reference: [jQuery AJAX](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/)